# SQL table comparison

Tags: query

Two tables Invoice and Allocation where both are connected with Invoice_Id_PK = Invoice_RK. There is a field in Invoice table called Allocated_Amount. I need sql query where Allocated_Amount is not null but has no reference of Invoice_Rk in Allocation table

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like it could be done using a NOT EXISTS expression

```
select inv.*
from invoice inv
where not exists (select *
                  from allocation alo
                  where inv.invoice_rk = alo.invoice_id_pk)
and inv.allocated_amount is not null;
```